# Java: design interface to force implementations to override toString

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, tostring

I'm developing an SPI and would like to define a `Reportable` interface such that any implementations must override `toString()` to something that is meaningful.

Is there any way in Java to write an interface such that any of its concrete implementations *must* override Object's `toString()`? For instance:

```
public interface Reportable
{
    public String toString();
}

public class Widget implements Fizz, Buzz, Reportable
{
    // ...

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

I know the above code doesn't *force* this kind of behavior, but is an example of what I'm looking for, i.e. if `Widget` doesn't override `toString()` you get a compile error because its violating the interface contract.

Comment: For abstract classes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8719482/force-tostring-implementation-in-subclasses

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force a class to override the .equals method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612273/force-a-class-to-override-the-equals-method). Should be the same for any method.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, you can't do this. I'd suggest you choose a *different* method name, e.g.

```
public interface Reportable
{
    String createReport();
}
```

That will force implementations to write an appropriate method. `toString()` is already somewhat vague in its intention - whether it's for debug representations, user-visible representations (at which point you need to ask yourself about locales etc). Adding *another* meaning doesn't seem like a good idea to me.

Answer (score 13):

What I understand is that you want to create a set of classes which neatly give their string representations. So that when something like `System.out.println(yourobject)` is called it shows meaningful data.

You cannot force your subclasses to override toString. But you can do something like this.

```
abstract class MyBase
{
    abstract String getNiceString();
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return getNiceString();
    }
}
```