# Enforce (re)implementing of existing method through interface contract?

Tags: java, interface

I have an use-case where I need the objects to provide sensible `String` output in `toString()` method (Not the default `Object.toString()` output). I was thinking of enforcing `toString()` method implementation through an Interface contract.

Something like,

```
interface TestInterface {
    public String toString();
}

class TestClass implements TestInterface {
    // But there's no need to implement toString() since it's already present as part of Object class.
}
```

But as in the comment, it doesn't **enforce** implementing the `toString()` method.

***I have 2 workarounds,***

Make the interface an **abstract class**,

```
abstract class TestInterface {
    public abstract String toString();
}

class TestClass extends TestInterface {
    // You will be enforced to implement the toString() here.
}
```

But this seems to be an overkill just to provide a contract. This will also mean the class cannot extend from any other class.

---

Change the method name to something else.

```
interface TestInterface {
    public String toSensibleString();
}

class TestClass implements TestInterface {
    // Should implement it here.
}
```

But this would mean, those classes which already override the `toString()` method needs to have an unnecessary method. Also it would mean only those classes which know about the interface will get the proper String.

---

*So, is there a way to provide a **contract** to (re)implement an existing method?*

Note: I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8719482/2775450) but that's related to Groovy I guess (and his problem is not a problem in Java at all).

Comment: If you use java 8, you might use a interface, with default methods implementations, which throws an exception, but this type of enforcement is at run-time, instead of compile-time

Comment: @RaduToader: [You cannot implement a `default String toString()` method in interfaces.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24016962/521799)

Comment: duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718112/tostring-equals-and-hashcode-in-an-interface

Comment: @RaduToader Unfortunately you can't. `It is a compile-time error if a default method is override-equivalent with a non-private method of the class Object, because any class implementing the interface will inherit its own implementation of the method.` And even if you could, your default method would never be invoked, as `Object` already provides a more specific implementation.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot enforce such a contract on an `Object` method from an interface. And you shouldn't. Relying on `Object.toString()` is not a good idea. This is your best approach:

```
interface TestInterface {
    public String toSensibleString();
}
```